# How can I make a function to Add Control in C#?

Tags: c#, function, controls

How can I make a function has 1 parameter recieves the type of the Control like(Button, GroupBox,Panel,TextBox,Label ...etc)

```
private void CreateControl()
{
   Button myButton=new Button();
   this.Controls.Add(myButton);
}
```

I need to put a paramter to spicify the type of the control not always a button.

Please help

Comment: `this.Controls.Add` method already does that for you. Why do you need one more?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) class is the base class for all Winforms controls. You can set the parameter to be of the base type, but it will also accept more derived types.

Try:

```
public void CreateControl(Control control)
{
    this.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

Comment: Why do he need that? He can call `this.Controls.Add` isn't it?

Comment: He wants to know how to accept a base class and use it on more derived types. I think his question more for basic polymorphism than the control class, at least that's how i take it. He can always use `this.Controls.Add` for adding controls to his form.

Comment: Actually he asked about passing in a __type__, not a ready made control. So the answer is both useless __and__ wrong. But since he accepted it, I guess he didn't really know what he asked..

Comment: I think i understood pretty clearly from his example what he ment to do, although he did ask it wrong. It is clear he doesn't want a **type**, but an already created **instance**.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to pass *type* you can do it via *generic*:

```
// Probably, you'd rather return T (created control), not void 
public void CreateControl<T>() 
  where T: Control, new() {

  this.Controls.Add(new T());
}
```

...

```
CreateControl<Button>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to complicate things using Reflection, you can create an `enum` and send that as a parameter :

```
public enum ControlType
{
    Button,
    Label,
    TextBox,
    //....
}
```

Then, your method call would be

```
private void CreateControl(ControlType control)
{
    switch(control)
    {
        case Button : 
            Button myButton=new Button();
            this.Controls.Add(myButton);
            break;
       //case etc
    }        
}
```